# How can I get my highlights out of Kindle? (the software, not the device)

Tags: mac, kindle

As I read Kindle books on my laptop I keep highlighting sections that I want to remember.

How can I export all the text that I highlighted so I can study it later on without having to flip through the book?

Ideally, I'd like to get it all out as text that I can copy and paste into a text doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your notes on Kindle titles are stored and accessible at https://kindle.amazon.com/your_highlights.

Comment: This is incredible! You just made everything I learn from reading infinitely more accessible. THANK YOU molgar!